# why do I get numbers when converting object into pd.datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, streamlit

[image]

```
df['logTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['logTime']).dt.floor('H').dt.time
```

I am using streamlit

Comment: Could you please provide some more details; what is your expected output, dtype etc. Also, it is very helpful to provide sample data as text, not image.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['logTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['logTime'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.floor('H').dt.time
```

Comment: ValueError: unconverted data remains: .0000000 
df['logTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['logTime'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.floor('H').dt.time
this result the same output of number

Comment: 'logTime' is object?

Comment: @walikyuyudin - see also updated answer above